# How to overcome 'lack of local experience'

Tags: resume

I am a software engineer from Australia and at the moment I work remotely for an **American IT firm**. I want to apply for a new job **in some Australian company** but the issue is that majority of the recruiters or HR managers prefer to invite local experienced candidates for interviews. Due to this fact my CV is being overlooked even being in Australia and the persons who have way less experience than me, say 4 years or 6 years less, they are called for interviews because they have been working in the local IT companies.

There is a similar question already posted [HERE](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13898/how-can-i-overcome-lack-of-local-experience) but the minute difference in the question is the physical presence of the job seeker. That OP was not physically in the country he was targeting whereas I am already in the country I am targeting.

What suggestive points can I mention in my CV or cover letters to get interview calls?

Comment: Is it possible that those companies were looking for less experienced people? 4-6 years less experience is quite a lot.

Comment: I'm curious to know how you're aware of who is being called for interviews (when it's not you) and how much experience they have. But I guess that's beside the point of the question.

Comment: I'm a little unclear on the meaning of "local experience". Software engineering is software engineering. Is the local experience related to the business domain e.g. legal, regulatory and compliance?

Comment: Does your CV and cover letter make it clear that the job you have is not based 
in America and you're currently in Australia? Because the problem is likely either they don't realise you're in (and from) Australia or with something in your application unrelated to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the issue is that majority of the recruiters or HR managers prefer to invite local experienced candidates for interviews.

This is a little weird. It's not something I have heard of before.

Coding is coding. Local experience is only going to be relevant for corporate culture and dealing with clients.

So I would start by challenging the recruiters or HR managers as to why local experience is more relevant (I'd love to find out why). Sometimes these people are far removed from the people who actually want you to do the work so they don't actually know what is involved.

As the barrier may be that people are not sure that you will be a fit with local people then it is time to prove yourself.

Try contacting development managers directly. If there are companies that you would like to work for that you think are looking for work. It never hurts to contact someone and explain that you have been working remotely for X years but now would like to work more local. Even if they are not looking currently if you have a good work record and seem worth employing they will remember you.

If you live in a city big enough to have tech meetups, go along and start to cultivate a network of people you know.

Recruiters and HR managers have their place, but they are sometimes an unnecessary obstruction. If you can get in contact with fellow developers you may be able to circumvent them.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to your question is similar to answers on just about any resume/CV question:

**Figure out what they're looking for, then emphasize those points when you write the content of the CV. If you don't have what they're looking for, go get it - or refocus your job search.**

You seem to have determined that your target employers want someone with local experience - but you're stating that you don't have any. Since you can't directly emphasize local experience, the least you can do is de-emphasize the non-local nature of your non-local experience. List your employer but don't list or don't emphasize their location.

Secondly, if you have involvement in projects of local interest - ie you're contributing to Australian-led open source projects, or involved in Australian programming organizations/clubs/etc, be sure to mention that. If you're not doing any of those things, consider starting, as a way to get "local" keywords on your resume.

Thirdly, regardless of how well you tailor your resume, you can also tailor your job search. I'm sure this is obvious, but it may be worth focusing on local employers who don't specifically require local experience - at the least, you can do this to get a foot in the door in terms of having a local employer on your resume, even if the position isn't you dream job in terms of the actual work you'd be doing.

Comment: "focusing on local employers who don't specifically require local experience" - or focus on local employers who *want* international experience